# best jquery-based lightbox / popup dialogbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog, lightbox

i'm looking for a jquery-based popup dialog box that we will use for :

1. displaying static content pages (terms of use, etc)
2. the contact us page (already uses the jquery form plugin for ajax submit)
3. displaying full-size for photo thumbnails.

can anybody recommend one that can fulfills all the above and that is rather lightweight and easy to use ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Fancybox - http://fancybox.net/

Handles pretty much any kind of content, rather easy to use and configure, and should work in most browsers.  Needs a little fix for IE8 though I think, but you can find that on the site or google it easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)? It's got quite a bit of features and you can customize the library for only the things you need.

Comment: Yes I have, and decided it was a bit too heavy for what I need.

Comment: In what sense? Both the themes and JS are hosted on Google's CDN meaning you don't need to install it or download it to your production site.

Comment: i mean heavy for the client, i host on s3 so bandwidth,etc is not an issue for me.